# авторизация VK invalid token C#

Tags: c#, вконтакте, авторизация, token

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь разобраться с авторизацией через различные сервисы, начал с вконтакте, прошерстил много форумов и прошел почти весь алгоритм, но возникли проблемы с подтверждением валидности пользователя (момент когда нужно отослать токен пользователя и 2 параметра от приложения). Пока что я пытаюсь все это проверить через браузер. Мои действия:

1) `https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=ИД_МоегоПриложения_ВК&client_secret=Секретный_Ключ_Моего_Приложения&v=5.37&grant_type=client_credentials`. Возвращается нормальный json такого вида:

```
{"access_token":"тутДлинныйТокенМоегоПриложения","expires_in":0}
```

2) Ничего не обновляя делаю авторизацию пользователя (только в новой вкладке) `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ИД_Моего_Приложения&redirect_uri=blank.html`
Теперь уже возвращается URL в браузере такого вида `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#code=Тут_Токен_Авторизованного_Пользователя` он не большой длины, вот FaceBook возвращает еще и ИД пользователя, вк такого не делает(не возвращает ИД?)

3) Ничего не обновляя, только открыв новую вкладку я делаю проверку авторизации пользователя в моем приложении по такой ссылке (все данные взяты из ответов предыдущих ссылок)
`https://api.vk.com/method/secure.checkToken?token=Из_2го_пункта_Токен_Авторизованного_Пользователя&v=5.37&client_secret=Секретный_Ключ_Приложения&access_token=Из_1го_Пункта_JSON_объекта`
В ответ приходит JSON объект с ошибкой о инвалидности токена, я так понял токена, который передался как самый первый аргумент

```
{"error":{"error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: Incorrect token invalid_token","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},
{"key":"method","value":"secure.checkToken"},
{"key":"token","value":"токен пользователя"},{"key":"v","value":"5.37"},
{"key":"client_secret","value":"секретный ключ моего приложения"}]}}
```

Я заметил что при обновлении первых 2х пунктов, постоянно меняется токен приложения или пользователя, поэтому я уточнял, что я ничего не обновлял. Проверяю я это все в браузере, но думаю эффект будет аналогичный. Помогите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? нашел какой-то форум, там проблема была в том, что нужно было добавить к ссылке еще `scoupe=offline`, но мне это не помогло.

Comment: Почему на третьем шаге в запросе вы указываете версию API где-то в середине? Согласно документации, она указывается в конце. И зачем там client_secret? Насколько я понимаю вам нужно указать только имя метода, параметр token и access_token. Попробуйте запросить secure.checkToken?token=Из_2го_пункта_Токен_Авторизованного_Пользователя&access_token=Из_1го_Пункта_JSON_объекта&v=5.37

Comment: Без client_secret выдает ошибку "User authorization failed: you should pass client_secret param to use secure methods", так что, выходит, нужно передавать секрет приложения,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором пункте не должен он у вас `code` возвращать, [должен возвращать](https://new.vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user?f=3.%20Receiving%20access_token) в параметре `access_token`. Посмотрите на пример [здесь](https://new.vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user?f=1.%20Opening%20Authorization%20Dialog) и попробуйте использовать для авторизации юзера следующий запрос:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id={ИД приложения}&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends&response_type=token&v=5.37
```

UPD: если это сайт, то нужно использовать немного [другой](https://new.vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user) тип авторизации. Всё делится на два этапа. **Первый** этап такой же, только в параметр `redirect_uri` вместо `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html` нужно подставить адрес вашего сайта, куда будет сделан редирект. В мане по поводу `redirect_uri` сказано дословно следующее:

> домен указанного адреса должен соответствовать основному домену в
>   настройках приложения и перечисленным значениям в списке доверенных
>   redirect uri — адреса сравниваются вплоть до path-части

По завершении этого этапа вы (ваш сайт) [получит](https://new.vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user?f=3.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20code) как раз таки параметр `code`

А на **втором** этапе вам нужно [получить](https://new.vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user?f=4.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20access_token) `access_token`, используя полученный на первом этапе `code`. В мануале указано что есть ограничения по времени на выполнение этого этапа:

> Параметр code может быть использован в течение 1 часа для получения
>   ключа доступа к API access_token с Вашего сервера.

```
https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id={ИД приложения}&client_secret={Секретный ключ}&redirect_uri={тот же адрес, что и на первом этапе}&code={полученный на первом этапе code}
```

Тут отмечу также что используемый `redirect_uri` должен совпадать с тем, что был использован на первом этапе:

> URL, который использовался при получении code на первом этапе
>   авторизации. Должен быть аналогичен переданному при авторизации.

И вот эти вот два этапа -- это только авторизация пользователя, т.е. только второй пункт вашего вопроса. Время жизни полученного `access_token` может быть конечным, через некоторое время его придётся обновить (видимо, только второй этап).

Comment: Здравствуйте, заменив ссылку во 2м пункте на вашу, я получаю редирект, и уже в адресной строке присудствуют следующие выражания https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token={Длинный токен, походий на accessToken моего приложения}&expires_in=86400&user_id={короткий набор цифр}. Скопировав access token в 3ю ссылку (вместо параметра token) получаю следующий ответ {"error":{"error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: Application should be native","request_params" и дальше параметры переданные мной}. Т.е. приложение должно быть родным? Повторюсь, что я делаю эту авторизацию и проверку через браузер

Comment: При попытке подставить в поле token. ID пользователя (9 цифр) то возвращает ошибку, invalid token

Comment: PS забыл указать, что приложение, которое я использую (секрет и ИД) было зарегистрировано в приложениях вконтакте как САЙТ, это имеет значение?

Comment: @simplygood , обновил ответ т.к. в комментариях отсутствует часть возможностей по форматированию.

Comment: Спасибо, надеюсь поможет, я так понял, что вконтакте настолько все сурово, что я просто так с браузера это не проверю, мне нужно включать сервер (проект на ASP, localhost), иначе вот эта проблема будет возникать с нативностью (я счел, что это именно из-за этого)

Comment: @simplygood, вроде можно и из браузера проверить. ВК после авторизации переадресует юзера на ваш сайт, при этом сам юзер тоже может вытащить code из URL. Но не зная параметров вашего приложения (ID и секретный ключ) он не сможет получить от имени вашего приложения свой access_token.